# Why this simple hql query doesn't work? uncategorized SQLException

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, hql

I have two tables: Research and userResearch, Research has userResearches list mapped to userResearch using @OneToMany. I'm trying to execute a simple hql query

```
from Research r inner join r.userResearches ur where ur.user=:user
```

and get this exception:

```
Hibernate operation: could not execute query; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select...]; SQL state [24000]; error code [0]; Operation requires a scrollable ResultSet, but this ResultSet is FORWARD_ONLY.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Operation requires a scrollable ResultSet, but this ResultSet is FORWARD_ONLY.
```

What can be the reason?
Entities are mapped right, everything works fine, I can retrive both entities using criteria API.

```
@Entity
public class UserResearch extends ManagedEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "research_id")
    private Research research;

@Entity
public class Research extends ManagedEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "research")
    private Set<UserResearch> userResearches = new HashSet<UserResearch>(0);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a different Collection interface, a `List` for example? The issue is probably not in the query itself, as it looks reasonable, but I can't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know the particular reason, but I rewrite a query using getSession().createQuery() and it started working, before I was using our GenericDao it uses getHibernateTemplate.

Comment: Ah, a leaky abstraction then probably :)